# ViewPager in Fragment Not Showing

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a parent FragmentActivity with some buttons, each button opening a child Fragment. One of the fragments ( Fragment A ) contains only a full page view pager that displays two other Fragments: B and C. When I firstly open Fragment A the view pager works fine and B and C appear. If I click a button opening another Fragment and then click back on Fragment A, B and C don't appear anymore.

Any ideas? I have tried a lot of things already

Code from fragment A:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
ViewPager vpPager;
private FragmentActivity myContext;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentA, container, false);
    vpPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(myContext.getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    adapterViewPager.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: 
                return new FragmentB();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentC();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

And the code from the parent FragmentActivity for the button that opens Fragment A:

```
public void onClickFragmentA(View v) {
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, new FragmentA()).commit();

}
```

Comment: Would you care to share your solution?  I am having the same issue i.e. fragments in my ViewPager don't show once the containing fragment has been paused and resumed.

Answer (score 0):

In FragmentA, reinitialize your UI components in onResume() method.

```
View rootView;

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initializeUIComponents();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentA, container, false);
    initializeUIComponents();
    return rootView;
}

private void initializeUIComponents(){

    vpPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(myContext.getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
}
```